# Making sections stick to top by adding class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a page where as each section reaches the top of the window, it will add a sticky class to the element to it becomes fixed to the top of the page.

I am trying to make the end result look like a bunch of pages that come up and stay at the top of the window

This is my code so far:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      var stickyTopSection = $('.home, .about, .gallery, .contact').offset().top;
    var stickyTop = function(){
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollTop > stickyTopSection) {
               $(this).addClass('sticky');
           } else {
               $(this).removeClass('sticky');
           }
       };

       stickyTop();

       $(window).scroll(function() {
           stickyTop();
       });
});
```

```css
.home, .about, .gallery, .contact{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.sticky{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.home{
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.about{
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.gallery{
    z-index: 3;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.contact{
    z-index: 4;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="home" class="home">
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
            </header>

            <section id="about" class="about">
                <h2>About</h2>
            </section>

            <section id="gallery" class="gallery">
                <h2>Gallery</h2>
            </section>

            <section id="contact" class="contact">
                <h2>Contact</h2>
            </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check each element individually, and what you have won't do that.  Try this...

```
var stickyTopSections = $('.home, .about, .gallery, .contact');

var stickyTop = function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    stickyTopSections.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (scrollTop > $this.offset().top) {
            $this.addClass('sticky');
        }
        else {
            $this.removeClass('sticky');
        }
    });
};

stickyTop();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    stickyTop();
});
```

`stickyTopSections` is a collection of elements, so each has to be parsed individually, hence the use of `.each()`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning), it's designed to solve this exactly problem. Support of it is [quite good](http://caniuse.com/#search=sticky), but if it's not enough you could youse [this great polyfill](https://github.com/AurelioDeRosa/audero-sticky).

Comment: when i use 'position:sticky', my inspect element says its an invalid property value

Comment: @Jason You probably use browser which doesn't support this feature (you can check with caniuse link I provided), you can use polyfill in that case.

Answer (score 0):

i have try with this other jQuery, is this what you need ?

```js
function isElementInViewport (el) {
      //special bonus for those using jQuery
      if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
        el = el[0];
      }
      var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
      return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && /*or $(window).height() */
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) /*or $(window).width() */
      );
    }
 
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
      //console.log("onscroll event fired...");
      // check if the anchor elements are visible
   
      $(".common").each(function (idx, el) {
   var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if ( isElementInViewport(el) ) {
          // update the URL hash
    $(this).addClass('sticky');
        }
  else {
   $(this).removeClass('sticky');
  }
  
      });
});
```

```css
.common {
 width:100%;
 height:100vh;
}
.home {
 background:#666;
}
.about {
 background:#999;
}
.gallery {
 background:#990;
}
.contact {
 background:#06C;
}
```

```html
<div class="home common"></div>
<div class="about common"></div>
<div class="gallery common"></div>
<div class="contact common"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```